# Cannot implicitly convert 'DataTable' to 'Task<DataTable>'

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I am getting Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'

The **GetExternalMessage** is taking Time to execute and hence the WinForm Stops responsing.
Hence I thought of appling "Task Await". But still i am getting error. How can we return a dataTable in Task?

Below is the code I am trying:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dtFrom.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
    dtTo.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    //dt =  GetExtMsg(dtFrom.Text, dtTo.Text);

}

async Task<DataTable> GetExtMsg(string dateFrom, string dateTo)
{
    DL dl = new DL();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt =  dl.GetExternalMessage(dateFrom, dateTo);
    Task<DataTable> tastDT = dt;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

As the error says, you cannot implicitly (or explicitly for that matter) convert a `DataTable` to a `Task<DataTable>`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx):

`You specify Task<TResult> as the return type of an async method if the return statement of the method specifies an operand of type TResult.`

Therefore you should just return the `DataTable` object from your method like so:

```
async Task<DataTable> GetExtMsg(string dateFrom, string dateTo)
{
 DL dl = new DL();
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt =  dl.GetExternalMessage(dateFrom, dateTo);
 return dt;
}
```

To consume this `async` method, you should use the `await` keyword before the method name, like so:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 dtFrom.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
 dtTo.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt = await GetExtMsg(dtFrom.Text, dtTo.Text);
}
```

Comment: How can I use this **GetExtMsg** in Button1_Click()?

Comment: I have updated my answer, but a sample of `async...await` is already given in the MSDN link that I have included in answer.

Comment: I am Still Not able to get the responsive Window. It just hangs when executing the function.

Comment: 1. That is impossible to answer without seeing other code involved. 2. That is a separate question. Please ask a new question and link this one if necessary. Thanks.